# Incrementing an array 'b' after receiving input of array 'a'

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to write the contents of an array after a method call.

EX:

```
int[] a1 = {7, 5};

mystery(a1);
```

---

```
int[] a3 = {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1};

mystery(a3);
```

---

```
int[] a5 = {-1, 1, -2, 16, 3, -3, -4, 5);

mystery(a5);
```

I've tried to write the output on paper going over each function for each iteration. But unable to make sense of how the method works.

```
    public static void mystery(int[] a) {
        int[] b = new int[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] >= 0) {
                int x = a[i] % 2;
                b[x]++;
                a[i] = b[x];
            }
        }
    }
```

Expected output of array `a1` is `{1, 2}`, but I'm trying to make sense of the process behind reaching these values in the new array.

Comment: Which part of the code do you not understand? Is there a specific line that confuses you? Because each line is quite straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

This loop modifies all the non-negative elements of the array `a`:

- x determines if a[i] is even (0) or odd (1)
- b[x]++ increments the counter of even (0) or odd (1) elements
- if a[i] is the n'th even number, it is assigned the number n
- if a[i] is the m'th odd number, it is assigned the number m

Hence, for an input array of two odd numbers - {7,5} - the output would be {1,2}, since 7 is the 1st non-negative odd number and 5 is the 2nd odd non-negative number.

Answer (score 0):

The method works in the following manner:

It keeps a count of all non-negative even numbers in b[0] and all non-negative odd numbers in b[1]

Now, it modifies the non-negative number in the array "a", such that it now represents as follows:
    if a[i] were an even number then it now represents it is Nth even number
    if a[i] were an odd number then it now represents it is Mth odd number

Or in other words

b[0] gives the count of all non-negative even numbers in the array "a"
b[1] gives the count of all non-negative odd numbers in the array "a"
a[i] is now the count of all non-negative even/odd numbers encountered before and including a[i].

Whether a[i] gives the occurrence of even or odd number can't be determined as the existing values are overwritten. You need to have a copy of original a[i] to determine that!

Please note it makes no changes to the "a[i]" if it were a negative number